# Set Linux disk offline in Windows disk management (dual-boot setup)

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive

I've recently set up my machine to dual-boot Windows 10 + Ubuntu. Each OS has its own disk.

I'd like to keep Windows as far away as possible from the Linux disk. I noticed that disk management in Windows allows marking disks as 'offline'.

My questions:

1. What does that do *exactly*?
2. Is it advisable/helpful/beneficial to set the disk holding Linux to 'offline' in Windows?
3. Will this alter the disk in any way (i.e. write to it), potentially destroying my Linux installation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/754094/does-offline-in-disk-management-actually-turn-off-spin-down-the-disk

Comment: @DavidPostill Not a duplicate, I read the other question prior to asking. I'm specifically interested in the mechanism behind the 'offline' setting and if that incurs write access to the disk in question.